# net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File system error (12)

Tags: blackberry

I have created a tab bar which appears when I enter first time in database screen, this code is working fine. But when we go on another tab and again go on database screen tab  it throws an exception

net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File system error (12)

I have closed database properly.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to open database which already open.

In first tab, you have opened database connection but when you switch another tab then how you close your database connection.

You should close database connection before reopen.

see following link for more details

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29299/Opening_and_closing_databases_1585333_11.jsp

If you still not able to resolve your issue, please paste your database code.

Comment: I am closing database in finally block when I am going in another tab.

Comment: Hi user135063, please help the another users and paste your code so that any of the user can get solution for his/er answer. You should continue until final answer not appears. This would make your question more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

To open database code

```
public void openDb(){
    try{
        closeDb();
        // Open the database          
          URI uri =  URI.create("Go2Reward.sqlite");    
        Logger.debug("-----URI-----"+uri);
        _db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Logger.error("--------- in open db====="+e.getMessage()+"----"+e);
    }
}
```

// close database

```
public void closeDb(){
    try{
        if(_db != null)
        {
            Logger.debug("----close db---");
            _db.close();
            _db = null;
        }   
    }catch(Exception e){
        Logger.error(" ---------in close db" , e);
    }
}
```

code to get data from database is as follow

```
 public Vector getCategoryVector() {
    Vector categoryVec = new Vector();
    try{
        openDb();
        Statement statement = _db.createStatement("SELECT category FROM CategoriesTable");
        statement.prepare();
        Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor(); 

        Row row;
        while(cursor.next()) {
            row = cursor.getRow();
            categoryVec.addElement(row.getString(0));
        }

        cursor.close();
        statement.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("---error getCategoryVector---"+e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        closeDb();
    }
    return categoryVec;
}
```

but when i open the database it work fine but within 10 transaction it returns the exception net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File system out of resources

Comment: This code is works fine in blackberry simulator but on real device it gives the exception net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File system out of resources